# Using GPG keys for SSH authentication

Tags: ssh, gnupg

I'm trying to use my authentication subkey as an SSH identity. I have gotten ssh-add to display my smartcard containing this subkey, but when I try to ssh, it does not seem to use this subkey as an identity.

When ssh-ing with `ssh -vvv`

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering ED25519 public key: /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

`ssh-add -l`

```
4096 SHA256:*** cardno:*** (RSA)
4096 SHA256:*** (none) (RSA)
4096 SHA256:*** /home/wilhelm/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Comment: This only seems to be a log excerpt, are there any further log lines following?

Comment: @JensErat Yes there are, but none are out of the ordinary. It doesn't seem to take notice of my GPG authentication subkey

Comment: Some more lines seem pretty relevant: is SSH accepting any keys, completely denying authentication, switching to password authentication, ... -- at least all authentication-related lines (including the final result) are _definitely_ relevant and required for any proper answer to your question.